# Force DecimalFormat to throw ParseException if not all the string is parseable

Tags: java

I want to configure my `DecimalFormat` instance so that it fails to parse a string if not all the string is parsable.

If I run the below code, the output I get is:

> I could parse the string, and the result is: 2000

However I would like it to throw an exception because it contains non-digits: *MMM*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        Number n = df.parse("2.000.MMM,77");
        System.out.println("I could parse the string, and the result is: " + n);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't know if this is possible...maybe you can extend DecimalFormat and then add something like compare input and output length ("." etc. removed) check

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: requirment part is not clear: 

`I want to configure my DecimalFormat instance so that it fails to parse a string if not all the string is parseable.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add yourself a little utility method like this:

```java
    private static Number parse(DecimalFormat df, String input) throws ParseException {
        final ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        final Number result = df.parse(input, position);

        if (position.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
            throw new ParseException("could not parse input='" + input + "'", position.getErrorIndex());
        } else if (position.getIndex() < input.length()) {
            throw new ParseException("input='" + input + "' wasnt processed completely", position.getIndex());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It will throw an exception if the input wasnt processed completely

You could also extend `DecimalFormat` and add the above method like so:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

public class ThrowingDecimalFormat extends DecimalFormat {

    public Number parseSafe(String input) throws ParseException {
        final ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        final Number result = parse(input, position);

        if (position.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
            throw new ParseException("could not parse input='" + input + "'", position.getErrorIndex());
        } else if (position.getIndex() < input.length()) {
            throw new ParseException("input='" + input + "' wasnt processed completely", position.getIndex());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```